# appearance of curve $z= xy$ on intersection with surface $x^2+y^2=a^2$

Tags: definite-integrals

What does the curve of $z=xy$ look like ? To find the area of the surfaces for the part of $z=xy$ cut off by cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$ what will the intersection of the two surfaces look like?

Comment: Concerning visualization of 3d graphs, you can use this for example: https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake  Thank you for information about this site. Fantastic tool this  3d-plotter, if you know more such sites please give some info :)

Comment: @Widawensen My pleasure! For the 2D case I find this one very very helpful- https://www.desmos.com/calculator .As my school teacher used to say, a little plot can often help intuition a lot.. Now if we could only find an 
n-dimensional plotter.. :-)

Comment: I also forgot to thank @Mathematician ByMistake  its really helpful .